# Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules react-json-editor-ui

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am using react-json-editor-ui in next.js project but now it show this error

My Project next.js version ^10.0.3"

```
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules\react-json-editor-ui\dist\react-json-editor-ui.esm.js
```

Comment: are you add import 'jsoneditor-react/es/editor.min.css'; ?

Comment: @H9ee I have import it like this as per documentation
`import 'react-json-editor-ui/dist/react-json-editor-ui.cjs.development.css'`